# Здравствуйте, подскажите почему не отправляется ajax запрос

Tags: ajax

```
$("#registAdd").click(function(){
        var firstName = $("#name").val();
        var lastName = $("#lastName").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var phone = $("#phone").val();
        var password = $("#passwordAdd").val();
        var sex = $('input[name=sex]:checked').val();
        var day = $("#day").val();
        var month = $("#month").val();
        var year = $("#year").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/registAdd',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: '{"firstName": "'+ firstName + '", "lastName": "'+ lastName + '", "birthDate": "'+ year + '", "email": "'+ email + '", "password": "' + password + '", "sex": "'+ sex + '", "phone": "'+ phone + '"}',
            success: function(data){
                if(data.status==='OK'){
                    window.location.href="/home";
                }else{
                    alert(data.errorMessage);
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Что пишет консоль ?

Comment: Ничего и не пишет

Answer (score 0):

первое - вы не правильно формируете json, правильно будет так:

```
data: {firstName: firstName,lastName:lastName,birthDate: year,email:email, password:password,sex:sex, phone:phone}
```

если вы передаете все параметры формы, то правильнее будет присвоить форме id и в ajax передавать

```
$('#you_form_id').serialize()
```

и покажите ошибки консоли, скорее всего это из-за того что вы не верно передаете параметры

Comment: Здравтсвуйте, спасибо за ответ в том то и дело что ошибок нет а дебаг доходит до $.ajax({ и останавливается

Comment: не знаю, у меня код с исправленным json'ом работает, включите консоль обновите страницу и покажите скрин после нажатия на #registAdd